# javascript object method undefined

Tags: javascript, methods

So, i'm new to JS, and i have some problems with object methods.
the method buy() in the building object prototype should do what i defined for it, but it says "Undefined".

```
var bitcoins=9000; //for example
var bitcoinsps=0;
    function building(price, bps, name) {
    this.price = price;
    this.bps = bps;
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = 0;
}
building.prototype.buy = function buy() {

    if (bitcoins >= building.price) {
        amount++;
        bitcoins -= price;
        price *= 1.15;
        bitcoinsps += bps;
    }
};
```

NOTE: yes, i did create an instance.

i tried "building.blabla" and "this.blabla" when calling the vars, but nothing happens. what is wrong?

edit: my new code:

```
var bitcoins = 0;
var bitcoinsps = 0;
var build = new Array();

function building(price, bps, name) {
    this.price = price;
    this.bps = bps;
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = 0;

}
building.prototype.buy = function() {

    if (bitcoins >= building.price) {
        this.amount++;
        bitcoins -= this.price;
        this.price *= 1.15;
        bitcoinsps += this.bps;
    }
};
    build[1] = new building(70, 1, "Junky laptop");
    build[2] = new building(300, 4, "Average PC");
    build[3] = new building(1000, 15, "Gaming PC");
    build[4] = new building(5000, 70, "Dedicated Hardware");
    build[5] = new building(24000, 300, "Small cluster computer");
    build[6] = new building(100000, 1000, "Medium cluster computer");
    build[7] = new building(500000, 4500, "Large cluster computer");
```

Comment: you dont understand how javascript works, read that book : http://eloquentjavascript.net/ and try again. You cant use a language if you dont have a basic understanding of its core concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buy() has to use **this.blabla**. So change it implementation like this:

```
building.prototype.buy = function buy() {
    if (bitcoins >= this.price) {
        this.amount++;
        bitcoins -= this.price;
        this.price *= 1.15;
        bitcoinsps += this.bps;
    }
};
```

Also, you have to create a **building** instance using 'new'. For example:

```
var b = new building(1, 2, 'fred');
b.buy();
```

Comment: i have created an instance, just not in the code here.

Comment: OK, so try running my solution.

Comment: Didn't work, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: That's funny, it worked for me. Are you saying that no values changed at all?

Comment: none at all, i edited my post with the whole code.

Comment: You still have "building.price". It should be "this.price". Also, I do not see any calls to buyBuild().

Comment: ok thanks! it works! building.price was undefined so it couldn't reach the code inside the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to re-state the method name; the following code:

```
building.prototype.buy = function(){
    // function body
}
```

Will create an instance function `buy` of the `building` object. To use it, you need to create an instance of `building`:

```
var b = new building(/*params*/);
b.buy();
```

As well, as cybersam pointed out, usage of any member variables of the `building` class need to use the `this` keyword.

Comment: i have created the instance. i showed just a part of the code.